# Size of element of array C

Tags: arrays, c, sizeof

Consider the line `<type> array[SIZE_OF_ARRAY];`. Later I need to use the size of an element of this array (ie for a `fwrite`). However I might change the `<type>` in future, so can't have a fixed size. The solution I found was to use `sizeof(array[0])`. While it works for my case, it doesn't feel very pretty, and it would run into problems if the array could be empty. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: `sizeof (array[0])` (parenthesis redundant), or alternatively `sizeof *array` **is** the best way to get the size of array elements.

Comment: `sizeof *array` is evaluated at compile time, so it does not matter if the array is empty at runtime.

Comment: `sizeof *array` is idiomatic, will be recognized by experienced C programmers, and should be used in `malloc` and read/write operations in preference to using `sizeof (type)`. This is because `sizeof *array` is **always** the size of an array element even if the definition of the array is changed, whereas `sizeof (type)` becomes wrong when the type of the array is changed. (Also note: `sizeof` is not a function, so `sizeof array` is fine because `array` is an operand not an argument, and the parentheses in `sizeof (type)` are due to a grammatical need to set off a type, not an argument list.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if the array could be empty. Is there a better alternative?

Array may not be empty. It can be uninitialized. Nevertheless this expression

```
sizeof(array[0])
```

is in any case valid because the operand is unevaluated expression in the sense that there is no access to the memory (though the expression itself can be evaluated at run time if `array[0]` is in turn a variable length array).

An alternative expression can look like

```
sizeof( *array )
```

You may use either expression with the same effect.